# Rails: Activerecord : How to send params for I18n message inside errors.add for custom validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-i18n, custom-validators

I use Rails 4 with the Rails-i18n Gem and i want replace my hard coded string "300px" with a placeholder in my language translation file like %{minimum_resolution} in config/locales/de.yml

```
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        organisation:
          attributes:
            image:                 
              resolution_too_small:"Image Resolution should be at least %{minimum_resolution}"
```

The value in %{minimum_resolution} should come from my custom validation in
app/models/organisation.rb

```
  def validate_minimum_image_dimensions
    if image.present?
      logo = MiniMagick::Image.open(image.path)
      minimum_resolution = 300
      unless logo[:width] > minimum_resolution || logo[:height] > minimum_resolution
        errors.add :image, :minimum_image_size
      end
    else
      return false
    end
  end
```

How can i get the value from minimum_resolution into my yaml file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this, and let me know

```
  def validate_minimum_image_dimensions
    if image.present?
      logo = MiniMagick::Image.open(image.path)
      minimum_resolution = 300
      unless logo[:width] > minimum_resolution || logo[:height] > minimum_resolution
        errors.add :image, :resolution_too_small, minimum_resolution: minimum_resolution
      end
    else
      return false
    end
  end
```

Anyway, this is the syntax

```
errors.add :field_name, :message_key, {optional_param1: value1, optional_param2: value2}
```

and it has to be defined like this

```
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        [your_model]:
          attributes:
            [field_name]:                 
              [message_key]: "Image Resolution should be at least %{optional_param1} and %{optional_param2}"
```

Comment: Official docs regarding passing variables to translations can be found [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#passing-variables-to-translations)

Answer (score 0):

Rails 6+ :

The syntax is

```rb
errors.add :field_name, :message_key, optional_param1: value1, optional_param2: value2
```